# Excel Enable insertion in one column and Disable insertion in the rest Columns

Tags: excel

I would love to activate insertion in one Column in my Excel sheet but diable it in the rest columns . I use Protect sheet but it protects all my sheet.

How Can I make only one column enabled and the rest disabled ?

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 0):

1. Select the whole sheet using the very top-left square in the sheet
2. On the Home tab, in the Alignment group, click the small arrow to open the Format Cells popup window.
3. On the Protection tab, select the Locked check box, and then click OK to close the popup.
4. Select the column you wish to be enabled
5. repeat step 2
6. On the Protection tab, **unselect** the Locked check box, and then click OK to close the popup.
7. On the Review tab in the ribbon, in the Changes group, select Protect Sheet

Partial source https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/lock-cells-to-protect-them-cb7835f6-9c37-4161-bb53-d1c410acaf21